# Simple Math Problem #1

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Here is a simple math problem. Can you solve it?

Examples:

- 678+57-24*2 = 7
- 265+34-12*3 = 8
- 328+58-22*1 = 12

Problem:

> 541+13-21*0 = ?

**HINT 1:**

Will see if this hint makes any sense or will edit it in another way, sorry making hints are hard for this(atleast for me):P

> 678+ 57- 24* 2 = 7

**HINT 2:**

> (678+)(57-)(24*)(2) = 7

Comment: @I am the Most Stupid Person, Will add the Hint tomorrow till then you can try, I am sure someone will find the solution might be you:P

Comment: @Preet Is the answer is 21?

Comment: @rudra i think no but you can add a answer, you might be on right track

Comment: Anyone please explain the reason for down vote..? Is it because of hint or something else?

Comment: The first hint was kind of misleading. I thought we were supposed to fill in the blanks.

Comment: ibrahim mahrir, that's why I was confused too but @stack reader got idea from that, impressive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found if, but it is a bit complicated.

> The hint(added spaces) seems to imply that the symbols affect the previous number so.
> 678+ 57- 24* 2 = 7
> 21(6+7+8) 2(7-5) 8(2*4) 2
> 21 + 2 - 8 * 2 = 7 (Then I find a chain of formula with the resulting numbers that gives to proper answer for all 3 examples)
>
> 265+34-12*3 = 8
> 13 1 2 3
> 13 + 1 - 2 * 3 = 8
>
> 328+58-22*1 = 12
> 13 3 4 1
> 13 + 3 - 4 * 1 = 12
>
> Now if I apply that chain of equation(+-*) to the problem, I get
> 541+13-21*0 = ?
> 10 2 2 0
> 10 + 2 - 2 * 0 = 12
>
> Note that the final chain of equations is the same as the initial one, so basically we need to apply each equations 2 times, once within the number itself and then between each numbers.

Comment: You got it!! was just adding another hint:P that means my previous hint was correct:P.

Comment: @Preet A variation of the [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Nice one! Good job @ stackReader!