# A Simple Math Problem

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

I got to ask this question idea from when try to solve [Simple Math Problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57934/simple-math-problem).

Here is a simple math problem. Can you solve it?

Examples:

- $678 + 57 - 24 \times 2 = 3$
- $265 + 34 - 12 \times 3 = 1$
- $328 + 58 - 22 \times 1 = 4$

Problem:

> $541 + 13 - 21 \times 0 =\; ?$

Hint 01:

> Don't think too much... Even grade 5 , 6 student can solve this problem but think outside of the box.

**Update**

Hint 02:

> Answer is "[undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_(mathematics))". Find how answer become "undefined".....

Comment: Not a bad puzzle, but you should really rethink your tags. Just a math tag by itself is not a good fit and will have people searching in the wrong direction(and then raging when they find out what kind of answer it was). And if adding tags gives the solution away too easily, then some strong hints toward the kind of puzzle this is into your question.

Comment: @stackreader Thanks. I am new to here. So what is the best tag for this type of questions?

Comment: @stackreader And Varlam Dadiani's answer is not the answer what I thought when creating this question. Even it is a valid answer, there is a another answer which related to basic maths with  outside of the box thinking

Comment: Outside of the box thinking usually requires "lateral thinking" tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seriously? I spent all the time just for that?! Great job man... Definitely blessed with some brains ;)

Answer is:

> undefined as per link
>
>  because well, $x/0 = undefined$. In this specific example, I think the entire equation would be $541 - 13 + 21 / 0$.

Explanation:

> **Important:** Division before addition!
>
>  Reverse the sign, *plus* the numbers, then plus the solution's numbers.
>
>
>  $$ 678 + 57 - 24 \times 2 \\ = 678 - 57 + 24/2 \\ = 678 - 57 + 12 \\ = 21 - 12 + 3 \\= 12 \\= 3 $$
>
>  $$265 + 34 - 12 \times 3 \\ = 265 - 34 + 12 / 3 \\ = 265 - 34 + 4 \\ = 13 - 7 + 4 \\= 6 + 4 \\= 10 \\= 1 $$
>
>  $$328 + 58 - 22 \times 1 \\= 328 - 58 + 22/1 \\= 328 - 58 + 22 \\= 13 - 13 + 4 \\= 0 + 4 \\= 4$$

Explanation #2:

> [image]
>
>  Plus the numbers and reverse the sign.
>
>
>  $(2+4) / 2 = 6/2 = 3$
>
>  $(1+2) / 3 = 3/3 = 1$
>
>  $(2+2) / 1 = 4/1 = 4$

Comment: Your answer also valid.... But No, First numbers also related to this...... But same concept (undefined as per link Because 3/0 = undefined... This is correct)... But you are not allowed to remove other numbers. :-)

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson :( lol

Comment: @chirs +1 however great work friend,,, simply it means there are more solutions for problems.

Comment: You are in very very close to this question... "Plus the numbers and reverse the sign. " one part also correct in this sentence tooo... awesome... Not both... Just one part...

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson How about now?

Comment: @ChrisHappy : Sorry but l think last line in explaination #2, there should come **(2+2)/1=4/1=4** instead of **(2+2)/1=4/1=5**

Comment: @ChrisHappy Great work. You got it

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

> 1

Explanation:

> you are counting circles in numbers.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. Seems like a very valid answer to me. Maybe it'll help if you elaborate more on what you mean by circles and how it applies to the examples shown

Comment: Nitpicking: The eight doesn't really have circles, more like teardrop shapes. (I wasn't the one to downvote)

Comment: I thought of this one too - but it seemed too arbitrary to be correct

Comment: sorry for my bad English, but i think it is not hard to understand what i mean in word circles. Number 8 has 2 circles, number 0 has 1 circle, number 2 has no circles. I was talking about shape circle.

Comment: But 4's dont count?

Comment: 4 has triangle in it, not circle

Comment: This is a perfectly correct answer.. But this is not what I thought.. I will give second hint on tomorrow.

Comment: If counting circles in numbers, why is your answer 1 instead of 0? There are no circles in either 541,  13, or 21; it would then be 0 circles + 0 circles - (0 circles times 1 circle) = 0 circles. wouldn't it?

Comment: I believe Varlam was simply counting the circles in total, not performing any arithmetic on the number of individual circles in each number

Comment: Adam, you are right

Answer (score 1):

It could be(got idea from Varlam Dadiani's answer and  Daniel Duque's comment :P)

> 0

Explanation

> count circles in each number, then calculate mathematic equation using this count as numbers

Result

> 678+57−24×2=3 => 3+0-0 = 3  //(circle in 6 and 8)
>  So 541+13−21×0=? => 0+0-0 = 0