# Simple Math Problem #3

Tags: lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle

Previous Puzzles(Not linked to this one): [Simple Math Problem #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57934/simple-math-problem-1) and [Simple Math Problem #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58177/simple-math-problem-2)

Prove the equation:

> $-6439832+ = 9$

$-$ and $+$ are there just to tell that you can use only these two operations. Also no need to separate or rearrange numbers, just solve it in steps(Use operations alternately).

Example:

> [image]

Hint 1:

> The 1st and last go together and off, now turn of next 1st and last.

Hint 2:

> The operator is with end operands only [use end operands(one after other) to create new number] and use operators alternately!

Sorry if too easy or not good. Enjoy:)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this question is asking!

Comment: Sorry for that, See @sedricks answer he atleast got the idea!!

Comment: so is @sedrick the right answer then?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, he just got idea, I said use operations alternately but he mixed up them. If it makes any sense to you now

Comment: How can we create a second number, without separating the original number? We need two numbers for +/- operation. I did not understand that part.

Comment: Its just to make sure to not make different numbers like 64, 398, etc otherwise yes to add subtract obviously you do within two numbers but single numbers only in pattern. hope its clear now or my bad. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer:

> $ 6 - 4 + 3 - 9 + 8 + 3 + 2 = 9$

Comment: +1 for the right answer but this is not intended solution I said no need to separate numbers I want it to solve in steps like a flow diagram or some kind.

Comment: @Preet, what do you mean by solve it in steps? Do you mean showing each step individually?

Comment: sorry if not clear actually create a whole new no. from existing by these operations then again a new no. at last you will get 9. If clear now;)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you meant by solve it in steps:

> $6, 4, 3, 9, 8, 3, 2$ 
>  $10, 1, 12, 1, 5, 1$ 
>  $9, 13, 11, 6, 6$ 
>  $4, 2, 5, 0$ 
>  $2, 3, 5$ 
>  $1, 8$ 
>  $9$

Comment: could you show the operations that you used? I'm a little confused

Comment: From first line to second line: 6+4, 4-3, 3+9, 9-8, 8-3, 3-2

Comment: You got the idea but I think you are wrong in two steps of first row if i got it! Try to use operations alternatively. +1

Comment: What does "Use operations alternatively" mean? Do you perhaps mean alternately?

Comment: yeah my bad i always confuse these two;)

Answer (score 1):

Alternating plus and minus, like kraby15

> 6 + 4 - 3 + 9 - 8 + 3 - 2 = 9